# Iform file Serialization and Deserialization in c#

Tags: c#, ef-core-3.0

I am getting Iform file from api request and its receiving properly in httppost method and again serialize to json format and storing in azure.

After that,downloaded that json and trying to deserialize the json data into Iform file again but unable to do.

```
[HttpPost("UploadSingleFile")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Postasync([FromForm(Name = "file")] IFormFile formFile)
{
    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(formFile);

    var serResp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IFormFile>(json);

    return serResp;
}
```

**Error :** Could not create an instance of type Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IFormFile

Is this possible in ef core c# or any other approach available?

Comment: You'd be better off constructing an `HttpRequestMessage` manually and attaching your file to the message rather than trying to serialize it ( Its not json serialized *now* anyways... so why try to serialize it that way on the outbound? )

Comment: ... And in order to do that, you're most likely going to need to read the file as a stream into memory and then copy it to the outbound request

Comment: @pinkfloydx33, My requirement actually, I need to store the Iform file somewhere and will use in future if i need, so only creating as json format file and trying deserialization.

Answer (score 1):

You could not create members of Interface types

This code will not work

```
var formFile = new IFormFile();
```

You should use interface implementations instead

try

```
var serResp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FormFile>(json);
```

**EDIT**

I've found a dirty hack that will work for you :

```
    public class FormFileChild : FormFile
    {
        public FormFileChild(HeaderDictionary headers, Stream baseStream, long baseStreamOffset, long length, string name, string fileName) : base(baseStream, baseStreamOffset, length, name, fileName)
        {
            Headers = headers;
        }
    }
```

.....

```
var serResp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FormFileChild>(json);
```

This will work because Json.Net will instantiate `Headers` property with value from constructor, that could be created/initialized, because it is an instance of concrete type

Comment: No,We can't create object for Iformfile, please check your code and suggest any other solution if you have

Comment: @vijay thats what i said. Interface members can't be instantiated.

Comment: I tried FormFile instead of IFormFile but facing same issue only.

Comment: @vijay are you sure error is same? It still tells about `IFormFile`? Or maybe about `IHeaderDictionary`?

Comment: yes you right . Facing `IheaderDictionary` error

 Could not create an instance of type Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHeaderDictionary. Type is an interface or abstract class and cannot be instantiated. Path 'Headers.Content-Disposition', line 1, position 143.
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateNewDictionary(JsonReader reader, JsonDictionaryContract contract, Boolean& createdFromNonDefaultCreator)

Comment: @vijay added a solution to my answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216611/discussion-between-vijay-and-roman-kalinchuk).